# How can I split colors of the area under line chart after a certain threshold (beyond x-axis)

Tags: echarts, baidu

I'm using [Baidu's echarts library](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts)

How can I split colors of the area under a line chart after a certain threshold (beyond x-axis) using the areastyle?

Thank you!

Comment: http://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=line-aqi See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

The areastyle is applied to the series itself, and cannot be tied to individual datapoints. Because the area color actually marks the area *between* two datapoints.

**But..**, you can, however, create a workaround and create two linecharts, like so:

```
legend: {
    data: ['myLine']
},
series : [
    {
        name: 'myLine',
        type: 'line',
        areaStyle: {
            normal: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        },
        data: [400, 300, 101, 134, null, null, null]
    },
    {
        name: 'myLine',
        type: 'line',
        areaStyle: {
            normal: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        data: [null, null, null, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
]
```

By adding it manually to the legend, and by giving both series the same name. ECharts combines the two series to some degree, so both the legend and the animation are acting like it's a single series.

Also, make sure to connect the two lines, by adding a datapoint twice (see `134`). And you can customize the lines a little more with `lineStyle`, etc, to make them look better.

---

You can create a little demo by checking [the ECharts demo gallery](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=area-stack) and replace the series and legend data with the snippet above (you may have to click the blue *run* button).